# Dice probability problem collection

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I tag these questions as homework, as they are older exam questions and every year

Can you try to solve/explain how to solve with a method some of these?

If something is answered in an old post please post the link.

---

**1. We toss 2 dice. Using probability-generating functions compute the probability that their sum is 4.**

---

**2. We roll two different dice 10 times. What's the probability the first die to show a number greater than the number of the second die for 3 three times*?**

*I think they mean that this happens three times (and they don't care about the precedence of those 3 times out of 10)

---

**3. Consider a random experiment in which we roll consecutively two dice until "we get a sum of 10 for the first time". We denote the random variable $X$ which countsthe number of repetitions until the end of the experiment. Compute the probability-generating function of $X$.**

---

**To community**: I'm familiar with many terms of probability theory so with a good analysis I think I might understand your answers.

Reminder:Their diffictulty may seem easy to medium but not everyone is great at this.

Comment: Are we assuming 6-sided dice?

Comment: Yes for all of them

Comment: @AnnaK. Posting three questions in one and not expressing your thoughts on any of them might be poor style for this site; it would be helpful to try and figure out first what it is you're stuck on.  If you have no idea where to start on any of them, is it because you don't understand the terms?  You do understand what it's saying but have no idea how to go about solving?  Also, welcome to mathSE!

Comment: A comment unrelated to this question: at one stage you posted many questions in a single post, with solutions to the first two. The first one was not right.

Comment: I think you mean this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488613/a-dice-problem-and-a-ballot-box-problem . They forgot to put it out of hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:

The probability generating function for the total of a single die is
$$
G(z) = \frac16 (z+z^2+\cdots+z^6)
$$
The probability generating function of a sum is just the product of the two probability generating functions. So, the probability generating function for the sum of two dice will be
$$
G_2(z)=G(z)\cdot G(z)=\left[G(z)\right]^2 =
\left[\frac16 (z+z^2+\cdots+z^6)\right]^2
$$
The answer to your question will be the coefficient of $z^4$.

2:

If we roll two fair dice, there are three possibilities: the two results are equal, the first is greater than the second, or the second is greater than the first.  The sum of the probabilities of each of these events is $1$, and the probabilities of the second two events are equal. The probability that two dice are equal is $\frac16$, which means that there's a $\frac56$ chance that one of the other two occur, which means that the latter two events each have a $\frac5{12}$ chance of occurring.

The probability that the first one is greater than the other is then simply $p=\frac5{12}$. The probability that this occurs $3$ times out of $10$ trials total is

$$
\binom{10}{3}\left(p\right)^{3}\left(1-p\right)^{7}
$$

3:

First of all, we need the probability that two dice sum to $10$. This, as it ends up, is $p=\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{12}$.  The probability of getting a sum of $10$ on the first try is then
$$
p = \frac{1}{12}
$$
The probability of getting the first sum of $10$ on the second try is the probability of not getting $10$ the first try times the probability of getting $10$ on the second, which is
$$
(1-p)p = \frac{1}{12}\times\frac{11}{12}=\frac{11}{12^2}
$$
The probability of getting the first sum of $10$ on the $n^{th}$ try (extending the above logic) is
$$
(1-p)^{n-1}p=\frac1{12}\times\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)^{n-1}
$$
So, our probability generating function is simply
$$
\begin{align}
G(z) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X=n)z^n \\&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{12}\cdot\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)^{n-1} z^n \\&=
\frac{z}{12} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{11z}{12}\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
This expression can be simplified by noting that this is a geometric series.

Comment: I'm reviewing the first as far: from mathematica I guess 1/12 is the coefficient (therefor our probability) link to computation: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2F6%29*%28z%2Bz^2%2Bz^3%2Bz^4%2Bz^5%2Bz^6%29%29^2)

Comment: @AnnaK. $\frac1{12}$ is correct.

Comment: About the second: is there a formula for the result?

Comment: Is there a formula for which result? Do you mean the [probability of $k$ out of $n$ successful Bernoulli trials?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial#Definition) Do you understand the notation $\binom{10}{3}$?

Comment: Yes :) Binomial coefficient it's name by popularity. So Bernoulli does his experiment that has a success of rate k.

Comment: Yes, so to speak. The point is that we repeat an experiment $n$ times where the probability of success is $p$ and the probability of failure is then $q=1-p$. Under those circumstances, the probability of $k$ successes total is $$\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$$ An interesting way to derive this is to just take the probability generating function of a bernoulli trial $(q+pz)$, take it to the power of $n$, and expand the result.

Comment: Blimey Omnomnomnom :) . For the third problem now: First of all, since we throw the dice together do we have $36$ or $\frac{36}{2}$ overall choices? And why 3 instead of 2? 5+5 is one posibility and 6+4 is the other. Do we care if it's 6+4 or 4+6?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10535/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-anna-k)